# No capture Angular Properties in W3C Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, binding, web-component

I am trying to make a web component compatible with different development frameworks, in the rest of the frameworks I have tested it, but in Angular I am having a problem when binding with the properties.

The problem is the following, in my angular component, which will be the place where I will place the web component, I have prepared a series of values ​​that I want to pass to the web component during its initialization, and if those values ​​are altered, I will capture and process them under.

The fact of the matter is that when initializing the values, I do not receive any type of attribute from the Web Component side, and when altering the values, I also do not receive any type of reactive response.

I know that there are some frameworks for Web Components such as Lit Elements, but given the requirements of the project, I need to work with vanilla components and therefore with the Web Components standard (Shadow Root, Template, Custom Elements, etc ...)

I leave here a link to StackBlitz with a small playground so that this problem can be replicated: [Problem With Angular and Web Components](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-components-in-angular-ran3jd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for attributes so you should define it like that on the html:

```html
<d-counter [attr.count]="count" #dCounter></d-counter>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-components-in-angular-5nofn4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I was exploring that solution, the problem I have is it sets the values late (which is triggered in attributeChangedCallback), and not in the initialization phase (which is triggered in connectedCallback), if I have my component initialization logic here, It forces me to reinitialize the entire component, with the subsequent loss of initial performance that it would have. It is a good attempt to get closer to the solution, but I would like to see if the latter can be achieved, that the component is initialized along with the attributes.

Comment: hmm maybe it's because angular sets the attributes in the later stages of the lifecycle. I'll take further look into it later

Comment: If you discover something, I will edit the answer and include it as valuable information for people who may come across this question. Still, thank you very much for your interest, it is highly valued.